# I am trying to override some specific files in prestashop using a self made module but I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Multiselect extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'multiselect';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Author';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = [
            'min' => '1.7.0.0',
            'max' => _PS_VERSION_
        ];
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Multiselect Module');
        $this->description = $this->l('A module for multiselect functionality');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('displayOverrideTemplate') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayOverridePartial');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall() &&
            $this->unregisterHook('displayOverrideTemplate') &&
            $this->unregisterHook('displayOverridePartial');
    }

    public function hookDisplayOverrideTemplate($params)
    {
        if ($this->active) {
            $templateFile = $params['template_file'];

            // Replace the template file with your own template file
            if ($templateFile === 'catalog/product.tpl') {
                return $this->display(__FILE__, $this->getOverrideTemplatePath('product.tpl'));
            }
            
            // Add more conditions for each .tpl file you want to override
            // if ($templateFile === 'path/to/your/file.tpl') {
            //     return $this->display(__FILE__, $this->getOverrideTemplatePath('path/to/your/file.tpl'));
            // }
        }
    }

    public function hookDisplayOverridePartial($params)
    {
        if ($this->active) {
            $templateFile = $params['template_file'];

            // Replace the template file with your own template file
            if ($templateFile === '../../themes/leo_smitten/templates/catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl') {
                return $this->display(__FILE__, $this->getOverridePartialTemplatePath('product-variants.tpl'));
            }

            // Replace the template file with your own template file
            if ($templateFile === '../../themes/leo_smitten/templates/catalog/_partials/product-add-to-cart.tpl') {
                return $this->display(__FILE__, $this->getOverridePartialTemplatePath('product-add-to-cart.tpl'));
            }

            // Add more conditions for each .tpl file you want to override
            // if ($templateFile === 'path/to/your/file.tpl') {
            //     return $this->display(__FILE__, $this->getOverrideTemplatePath('path/to/your/file.tpl'));
            // }
        }
    }

    private function getOverrideTemplatePath($template)
    {
        return $this->getLocalPath().'themes/leo_smitten/templates/catalog/'.$template;
    }

    private function getOverridePartialTemplatePath($template)
    {
        return $this->getLocalPath().'themes/leo_smitten/templates/catalog/_partials/'.$template;
    }
}
```

At first i have made a child_theme but i don't know why, when i try to revert it back to the parent theme, the website became strange like it wasn't like before and to be able to let my website appear like before i needed to reset the database with one of my saved file sql.

So I did'nt want to use a child theme anymore. Then i have read somewhere that it's better to not do a override directly in the file because a dependance and update. And this is why i'm trying to use a module to override.

But my override doesn't work i don't know why. Like the php file work properly (because when i put some string inside like "nxeinchren" there are error that show up) but my tpl file do not override the original file in the template. It's as if my tpl file didn't exist. Even when i try to put anything (like "ncufencn") inside it, it doesn't react, not even some error message. Even the apache log doesn't show anything meaningful.

I need help please.

PS: I'm working in wampserver

The absolute path of one the file that I want to override:
C:\wamp64\www\testOverride\themes\leo_smitten\templates\catalog\product.tpl

The absolute path of the file that i want to use to override:
C:\wamp64\www\testOverride\modules\multiselect\themes\leo_smitten\templates\catalog\product.tpl